# Specific Routing In ASP.net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I'm making a simple website in Asp.net MVC 4. I'm using default Identity models. There are many partial views that I am using.

The problem is that if someone passes the path to a partial view, the view opens up but all messed up (because it's a partial view). But I want to restrict anyone from opening a partial view except from some within some view and not by simply putting the link in the address bar and hitting enter..

For example the `localhost:1234/abc/MainPage` view may open the `MainPage` and this `MainPage` may open up a partial view (`PView` for example)  but simply by putting `localhost:1234/abc/PView` should not open any view and should redirect to its parent view eg `MainPage`. Is there any method to do that? Similar to what we do for checking roles and authorization via Identiy model i.e.  `[Authorize]` tag

Answer (score 2):

You can mark your action as a child action

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult ActionForMyPartial()
{
    ...
}
```

If it is handled by AJAX requests you can check that it matches the request

```
public ActionResult ActionForMyPartial()
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView();           
    }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand at all but i think you are looking something like this: `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` you can use that adding above your method that is rendering the partial view like this 
`[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult renderMyPartial(string myparam)
{
      //some code
}`

i hope this help you.